# Rows to columns by 2 Ids and minimum date - SQL

Tags: sql

I got this table:

[image]

```
Correo;           Fecha_Evento; Id_Comunicacion;Tipo_Evento
claudio@gmail.com;5/17/2021 18:02;1826;Apertura
claudio@gmail.com;3/31/2021 17:02;1826;Entregado
claudio@gmail.com;11/30/2020 17:00;1865;Entregado
claudio@gmail.com;5/24/2021 12:05;1865;Apertura
claudio@gmail.com;6/28/2021 13:45;2031;Entregado
claudio@gmail.com;7/26/2021 15:14;2031;Apertura
claudio@gmail.com;7/26/2021 20:15;2031;Apertura
rodrigo@gmail.com;2/9/2021 10:46;1826;Apertura
rodrigo@gmail.com;12/3/2020 10:16;1826;Entregado
rodrigo@gmail.com;1/13/2021 18:00;1865;Entregado
rodrigo@gmail.com;1/17/2021 13:32;1865;Apertura
rodrigo@gmail.com;6/17/2021 13:32;5001;Entregado
rodrigo@gmail.com;6/30/2020 17:00;5001;Apertura
rodrigo@gmail.com;7/17/2021 13:32;5001;Apertura
```

and I want to transform to this:

[image]

I want to transform the the column "Tipo_Evento" to rows with "Fecha_Evento" values, but there are some cases where I got two values for "Apertura" and in these cases, I want the min date, the min "Fecha_Evento". For example, for the "claudio" mail , the "2031" Id_Comunicacion and the "Apertura" Tipo_Evento, I want to keep the orange (line 7) and not the 8 line in blank because between these two "Apertura" values I want to keep the minimun date (Fecha_evento)

I've tried something like this but I don´t get the desired:

```
SELECT Correo,  Id_Comunicacion , 
        
        (case when Tipo_Evento = 'Entregado' then Fecha_Evento end) Entregado,
        (case when Tipo_Evento = 'Apertura' then Fecha_Evento end) Apertura
        
        

FROM    table
WHERE    Correo IN ('rodrigo@gmail.com','claudio@gmail.com')
GROUP BY    Correo,  Id_Comunicacion, Tipo_Evento, Fecha_Evento
ORDER BY Id_Comunicacion DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the sample input as text we we can use it to generate a solution.

Comment: Remove `Tipo_Evento, Fecha_Evento` from `GROUP BY    Correo,  Id_Comunicacion, Tipo_Evento, Fecha_Evento`

Comment: @dougp Done! I'll be careful care with that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want aggregation like this:

```
SELECT Correo, Id_Comunicacion,         
       MIN(case when Tipo_Evento = 'Entregado' then Fecha_Evento end) as Entregado,
       MIN(case when Tipo_Evento = 'Apertura' then Fecha_Evento end) as Apertura
FROM table
WHERE Correo IN ('rodrigo@gmail.com', 'claudio@gmail.com')
GROUP BY Correo,  Id_Comunicacion
ORDER BY Id_Comunicacion DESC
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed MAX per MIN because I wanted the minimum date. Thanks!